# GPUImageUIElementFilter returning video with white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I've gone through several examples of the new `GPUImageUIElementFilter`, and have tried applying them to a video I have from disk, but am getting a "white screen" video instead. I've tried running the code with other filters (sepia, pixelate), and it seems to be working fine, however the blending with ui elements is failing.

Here is my code:

```
//Declared in interface

@property(nonatomic, strong) GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GPUImageMovie *movieFile;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GPUImageFilter *blendFilter;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GPUImageUIElement *uiElementFilter;



- (void)videoOutputOverlay {

  self.movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:self.post.url];
  self.movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
  self.movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
  self.blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
  ((GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *)self.blendFilter).mix = 1.0;
  self.drawingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  self.uiElementFilter = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:self.drawingView];
  [self.movieFile addTarget:self.blendFilter];
  [self.uiElementFilter addTarget:self.blendFilter];

  // In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
  NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Output.m4v"];
  unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

  self.movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
  [self.blendFilter addTarget:self.movieWriter];

  // Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
  self.movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
  self.movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter;
  [self.movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:self.movieWriter];

  [self.movieWriter startRecording];
  [self.movieFile startProcessing];

  __weak PostPreviewViewController *weakSelf = self;
  [self.movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [weakSelf.blendFilter removeTarget:weakSelf.movieWriter];
    [weakSelf.movieWriter finishRecording];

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, NULL, NULL);

    NSLog(@"completed saving movie");

  }];
}
```

This is all pretty much copied identically from some examples out there online, the main difference is that I'm using a file not live video.

On the exported video in my "camera roll", I can hear the audio + everything worked with other filters, so I am sure the video is loading correctly (plus not getting any errors on export)

I'm assuming there is something wrong in the way i set up the filters/targets.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs into this problem, I was able to somewhat solve it (just missing sound in my case now). Here is my code, mind it has some project specific things but is rather generic otherwise

```
- (void)videoOutputOverlay {

  movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:self.post.videoUrl];
  movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
  movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;

  filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
  //  [filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
  [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)filter setBrightness:0.0];
  [filter setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotateRight atIndex:0];

  GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
  //  [blendFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
  blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

  UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  [contentView addSubview:self.drawingView];
  [contentView addSubview:self.textOverlayView];
  uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:contentView];

  [movieFile addTarget:filter];
  [filter addTarget:blendFilter];
  [uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];

  // In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
  NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
  unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie

  //load asset to grab size
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.post.videoUrl];

  AVAssetTrack *track = asset.tracks.firstObject;
  CGSize exportSize = CGSizeMake(track.naturalSize.height, track.naturalSize.width);

  movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] size:exportSize];
  [blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

  __weak GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElement = uiElementInput;
  [filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *filter, CMTime frameTime) {
    [weakUIElement update];
  }];

  // Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
  movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
  movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
  [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

  [movieWriter startRecording];
  [movieFile startProcessing];

  __weak PostPreviewViewController *weakSelf = self;
  [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, weakSelf, @selector(image:completedSavingLocallyWithError:usingContextInfo:), NULL);
  }];
}
```